# OpenUI5 sample app runs into Cross-Origin Read Blocking issue

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I just tried the OpenUI5 QuickStart Tutorial.
Step 1 worked fine, in step 2 I get the following error message in Chrome.

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response

```
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.tutorial.quickstart/sample/resources/sap-ui-core.js with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for  more details. with the downloaded demo code.
```

I tried a local copy of openui5, but here I also get CORB issues (this time I tried with Safari):

[

```
Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/stefan/Documents/Development/Rezepte/openui5/resources/sap/ui/core/messagebundle_de_DE.properties due to access control checks.
    send (sap-ui-core.js:2213:81759)
    ajax (sap-ui-core.js:2213:76946)
    (anonyme Funktion) (sap-ui-core.js:217:942)
    (anonyme Funktion) (sap-ui-core.js:232:233)
    t (sap-ui-core.js:202:440)
    l (sap-ui-core.js:199)
    R (sap-ui-core.js:192:221)
    (anonyme Funktion) (sap-ui-core.js:203:98)
    (anonyme Funktion) (sap-ui-core.js:905:678)
    (anonyme Funktion) (sap-ui-core.js:887:965)
    promiseReactionJob
```

What do I need to do to get rid of the CORB issues while using OpenUI5?

Thanks and best regards,
Stefan

Comment: Solved the issue with the local copy of openui5 in a resources folder on my Mac and  going via Webserver (MAMP) and not via launching the browser on the local index.html as indicated. However, the issue with loading openui5 via https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com persists ...

Comment: You are accessing some weird test file. Simply use the official CDN link

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js